# PHP - Update data in databes by ID

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to overwrite the data in the database by ID.

I have a code:

index.php

```
Databes::updateData($_POST['URL'],$_POST['title'],$_POST['label'],$_POST['content'], $id);
```

Databes.php

```
public static function query ($sql, $parameters = array()){
    $query = self::$connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($parameters);
    return $query;
}

public static function updateData($URL, $titel,  $label, $content, $id){
    $query = Databes::query("
    UPDATE clanky
    SET (URL, titulek, popisek, obsah)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    WHERE clanky.clanek_id= " . $id
    , array($URL, $titel,  $label, $content));
}
```

I will get an answer:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(URL, titulek, popisek, obsah) VALUES ('uvodni-clanek', 'ÚvodníČl...' at line 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\Ukoly 5\2\tridy\databes.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\Ukoly 5\2\tridy\databes.php(26): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\Ukoly 5\2\tridy\databes.php(56): Databes::query('\r\n UPDAT...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\Ukoly 5\2\administrace.php(56): Databes::updateData('uvodni-clanek', '\xC3\x9Avodn\xC3\xAD\xC4\x8Cl\xC3\xA1ne...', '\xC3\x9Avodn\xC3\xAD', 'Ahoj, v\xC3\xADtej...', 6) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\Ukoly 5\2\tridy\databes.php on line 26

But if I overwrite it directly in the database. So the database will write to me that it did this:

```
UPDATE `clanky` SET `titulek` = 'ÚvodníČlánek' WHERE `clanky`.`clanek_id` = 6;
```

I tried variously to rewrite the query into the database according to what I found on google, but it still reports an Error.

Please someone don't know where I'm making a mistake?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: Why not using placeholder argument for ID too? If it's string (e.g. `123a`), then it must be quoted

Comment: SQL looks wrong. It's `UPDATE table SET field1='value1', field2='value2'`.

Comment: The syntax for updates are: `UPDATE table SET col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? WHERE id = ?`. The syntax you've posted is for inserts.

Comment: _Side note:_ You can change `clanky.clanek_id` to just `clanek_id`. You don't need to clarify the columns table name when you're just working with one table.

Answer (score 1):

You're using incorrect syntax - `UPDATE clanky SET (...) VALUES (...)` is not valid. What you need to do, and what you seem to be doing manually, is:

```
UPDATE clanky
   SET URL = ?
     , titulek = ?
     , popisek = ?
     , obsah = ?
 WHERE id = ?
```

Definitely do use parametrization for ID too, otherwise you're opening yourself up for SQL injection vulnerability (imagine someone passing id = 'id', you end up with WHERE id = id and all of your rows are getting updated)